# User Friendly Error page in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, exception

Whenever I am getting error like `Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object in /var/www/...Controller.php on line 143`, My symfony2-app shows a blank page in prod-environment. The above message available in dev-environment. I want to show a custom page in prod-environment for such errors. How can I implement it in Symfony2?

Update:
May `kernel.event_listener` help me?

Comment: You can create a [error controller](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html)

Comment: Why do you want to do that? That's a security risk to show to your users in production environment where the application has crashed? Hence you can only see it in dev mode

Comment: @RezaSanaie  Now It shows a blank page. I want to show some message like "something went wrong. try later".

Comment: If you such an error `Fatal error: Call to a member function getName` it seems like your code is not production ready yet and you should be using the dev environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot really implement that in symfony. Fatal errors are not handled by symfony but by the PHP extension itself. The Symfony code never gets a chance to finish executing because of the fatal error leaving php to handle the error by its own devices. PHP error handling is set by [error_reporting()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and the error_handler set by [set_error_handler()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php). In the dev environment, [php error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) is set to E_ALL to show all errors. In a production environment, errors and debug messages are set to 0 and are not displayed for aesthetic and security reasons (some error messages may display password, etc). The best advice would be to fix all fatal errors before deploying to production. To catch and display a custom page for fatal errors must be done using php set error handling - http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php.

For non-fatal errors, you can create a custom error page view that can be displayed - http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html

Answer (score 1):

I do it this way:

```
class ErrorExceptionHandler {

    function __construct() {
        register_shutdown_function(array($this, 'fatalErrorHandler'));
    }

    function fatalErrorHandler() {
        $error = error_get_last();
        if ($error['type'] === E_ERROR) {
            header('Location: /error-page-url');
        }
    }

}

ErrorExceptionHandler(); // add to app.php
```

Of course please remember about namespace etc.